# Why is E(dfa) a decidable language?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, dfa, turing-machines, decidable

I don't understand why the Turing Machine T, ACCEPTS when no accept state is marked and rejects when an accept state is marked:

> E(dfa) = {| A is a DFA and L(A) = the empty set(don't have the symbol)}
>
> E(dfa) is a decidable language.
>
> Proof:     A DFA accepts some string iff reaching an accept state from the start state by >traveling along the arrows of the DFA is possible. To test this condition, we can design a >TM T that uses a marking algorithm similar to that used in Example 3.23.
>
> T= "On input , where A is a DFA:
>       1. Mark the start state of A.
>       2. Repeat until no new states get marked:
>       3.    Mark any state that has a transition coming into it from any state that is 
>          already marked.
>       4.  If no accept state is marked, accept; otherwise, reject."

This seems backwards to me. Can anyone explain this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that your confusion results from the use of the words "accept" and "reject" in different contexts. At a high level, it's easy to avoid this confusion, because you can define your Turing machine, *T* to not refer to the process a DFA, *A*, does its own accepting and rejecting.

L(*T*) is { A | L(*A*) is empty }. This is the same as E(dfa) defined in your question, but using L(*T*) makes it more explicit that we're dealing with two separate languages here, one just happens to be defined in terms of another.

If we work from high-level to low-level, we can say:

- L(*T*) accepts A whenever L(*A*) is empty.
- But how do we determine whether L(*A*) is empty? Well L(*A*) is empty when *A* rejects all strings.
- How do we know a string is rejected in *A*? It does not end in an accept state.

We can also work from low to high now quite easily:

- If a string given to *A* does not end in an accept state, it is rejected.
- If all strings are rejected by *A*, then L(*A*) is empty.
- If L(*A*) is empty, then L(*T*) accepts *A*.

Now your proof goes into a bit more detail as to how *T* goes about deciding whether to accept *A* or not, but I think your confusion revolved more around the multiple uses of accept and reject. Very broadly, you can say *T* accepts *A* iff *A* rejects everything.